# Samsung note9 adb over USB keeps disconnecting

Tags: adb

I have my Samsung Note9 (updated, on latest Android 9) connected via USB on Ubuntu Linux, latest platform-tools_r28.0.1. When I run adb shell, it works perfectly. The problem is, the device disconnects after the while (about 30 seconds).

I have the "stay awake" option enabled, but even if the screen remains on, adb keeps disconnecting. I discovered when I prevent the phone from sleeping by touching it, adb remains connected.

Am I do something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try revoking USB authentication, reboot both devices, connect and authorize. May help - guessing

Comment: This scenario seems work: after the first disconnection, switch USB mode to charging only and turn-off, turn-on USB debugging without disconnecting USB.

Comment: Well, if that is consistent you can make that an answer

Comment: hmm, no, it worked just for a little bit longer...

Comment: Sounds to me like a defect USB port (loose connection)